# HTML5 - Fire event every few seconds while video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, settimeout

I want to track user engagement for a video, by tracking how many users are dropping of at different time interval.

For this I need to fire a tracking event, every 15 seconds while the video is playing.

The `playing` event is triggered once. I need something which I can use throughout the life of the video.

```
var _video = $('video')[0],
        timeoutID;
    $(_video).on('playing', function(event){
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("video is playing");
        }, 15000);
    }).on('ended', function(event){
        console.log("video eneded");
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `window.setInterval` instead of `window.setTimeout`

```
$(_video).on('playing', function(event){
        timeoutID = window.setInterval(function() {
            console.log("video is playing");
        }, 15000);
    }).on('ended', function(event){
        console.log("video eneded");
        window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `timeupdate` event instead, it updates whenever the video's `currentTime` changes, or in other words it updates as the video is playing and gives you the amount of video the user has actually seen

```
var _video = $('video')[0];

$(_video).on('timeupdate', function() {
    var hasPlayedTime = _video.currentTime;
});
```

```js
var _video = $('video')[0];

$(_video).on('timeupdate', function(event){
  var hasPlayedTime = _video.currentTime;
    
  $('#result').html('<strong>Elapsed : </strong>' + hasPlayedTime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video controls="" style="width:240px;height:180px;">
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" />
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" type="video/mp4;codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" />
</video>
<span id="result" style="position:relative; top: -100px; left: 20px"></span>
```

To act only every fifteen seconds on an event such as that, we need to add some math and logic

```js
var _video   = $('video')[0],
    debounce = true,
    seconds  = 5; // set to 15 instead

$(_video).on('timeupdate', function(event){
    var hasPlayedTime = _video.currentTime;
    var intPlayedTime = parseInt(hasPlayedTime, 10);
    var isFifteen     = intPlayedTime % seconds === 0 && intPlayedTime !== 0;
    
    if (isFifteen && debounce) {
        debounce = false;
        $('#result span').html(intPlayedTime); 
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            debounce = true;
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" controls="controls"></script>
<video controls="" style="width:240px;height:180px; position: relative; top: -20px; float:left">
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" />
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" type="video/mp4;codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" />
</video>
<span id="result" style="position:relative; top: 70px; left: 20px">
    <p><u>Updates every five seconds</u></p>
    <strong>Elapsed : </strong>
    <span>0</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this

```
var lastSecond = null;
var secondsToCallFunction = 20;
$(_video).on('timeupdate', function(e) {
 var seconds = Math.floor(e.target.currentTime);
 if (seconds % secondsToCallFunction  == 0 && lastSecond !== seconds) {
    lastSecond = seconds
    console.log(seconds);
}
});
```