# HTML5 Video - pause for a few seconds then continue playback

Tags: javascript, video

I have a HTML5 video element in my page and what I'd like to happen is when it reaches the 3 second mark, it needs to pause for 2 seconds and then continue playback.

The video length is about 8 seconds.

```html
<video id="video" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

Comment: You may try: `video.onended = ()=>{
  setTimeout(function(){ video.play(); }, time);
} `

Comment: You can use timeout, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33225485/2630817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it

```
const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
function playVid() {
    video.play();
    window.setTimeout(pauseVid, 3000);
}
function play() {
    video.play();
}
function pauseVid() {
    video.pause();
    window.setTimeout(play, 5000);
}
```

Comment: This has a potential problem: if the video has not loaded and started playing by the time this code runs, then it will not pause exactly at 3 seconds. Ideally this code should be wrapped in an event handler for the video load/play.

Comment: Thank you. This works only for the first time. When the movie restarts doesn't pause at 3 seconds.

Comment: I have edited the answer.                                                                                                                                   This one is a bit messy but does the job. Only problem is that, if you deliberately pause the video, you wont get the same pause and play effect.

Answer (score 1):

## <del>[`setTimeout()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097655/2813224)</del> [`.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) & [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate)

Go to the link above to understand why `setTimeout()` ain't so great.

### `.currentTime` Property

This property is used by `<audio>` and `<video>` tags to get/set playback time in seconds. In the following demo it is used to get the time:

```
var t = this.currentTime;
```

### `timeupdate` Event

This event fires 4 times a second while an `<audio>` or `<video>` tag is playing. In the demo both a `<video>` and `<audio>` tag are registered to to the `timeupdate` event:

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", tick);
timer.addEventListener("timeupdate", tock);
```

---

### Setup

#### `[controls]` Attribute

Added so the time can be reviewed as the demo runs, it's optional and recommended that it not be used in production.

#### `<audio>` Tag

An `<audio>` tag has been added as a timer, The attributes `[muted]` and `[autoplay]` are required:

```
<audio id='timer' src='https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEwMzM5OV8/righteous.mp3' muted controls autoplay></audio>
```

Both tags will start playing and are listening to the `timeupdate` event and will call a function at a predetermined time:

```
function tick(e) {
  var t = this.currentTime;
  if (t >= 3) {
    this.pause();
    video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", tick);
  }
}

function tock(e) {
  var t = this.currentTime;
  if (t >= 5) {
    video.play();
    timer.removeEventListener("timeupdate", tock);
  }
}
```

Basically when the `<video>` and `<audio>` tags are triggered every 250ms, they are calling those functions:

1. `<video>` calls `function tick()`
2. if the playback time is 3 or more seconds it pauses.
3. to avoid constant triggering every 250ms, the eventListener is removed.
4. `<audio>` calls `function tock()`
5. if the playback time is 5 or more seconds it will play the `<video>`.
6. for the same reason as the `<video>`, the eventListener is removed.

---

### Demo

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", tick);
timer.addEventListener("timeupdate", tock);

function tick(e) {
  var t = this.currentTime;
  if (t >= 3) {
    this.pause();
    video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", tick);
  }
}

function tock(e) {
  var t = this.currentTime;
  if (t >= 5) {
    video.play();
    timer.removeEventListener("timeupdate", tock);
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="video" playsinline muted loop controls autoplay width='300'>
  <source src="https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
<audio id='timer' src='https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEwMzM5OV8/righteous.mp3' muted controls autoplay></audio>
```